# Make a bubble chart in excel from a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, bubble-chart

Is there a way to make a bubble chart from a pivot table in excel? When I try do this I get a message that says that bubble charts and stock charts doesnt work with pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the pivot table to stay dynamic? And if so, will the pivot table change in size?
If the answer to either of these is no, these work-arounds should work:

---

### option 1 - You only need the values from the pivot table

Make a copy of the pivot table, but paste only the values.
Now you can make a bubble chart.

---

### option 2 - The pivot table values may change, but the dimension would stay the same.

make a copy of the pivot table, but put in each cell a reference to the corresponding cell (e.g. `=E15` ) in the original pivot table.
Now you can make a bubble chart.

---

edit:

### option 3 - Everything needs to stay dynamic

- Use a pivot chart instead of a pivot table. see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c).
- Its also possible to convert your existing table into a pivot chart.
  see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c#__toc336601667).

edit 2: option 3 seems not to work for bubble charts after all. I leave this option here for completeness’ sake.

Comment: Both the table and the chart need to be dynamic.

Comment: And the dimensions might change? say from a 5 by 4 table to a 5 by 5?

Comment: But the message is that I cant use bubble charts.

Comment: Ah, now I see the comment you refer to. So it seems theres no easy way to do it after all. Sorry. See if the suggestions [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/pivot-table-and-buble-chart.1041144/) work for you. otherwise try to some variations of the workarounds I suggested.